# What is the difference between these scopes in the configuration of a proxy in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, http-proxy

I am creating proxies configurations with a chrome extension, but I do not differentiate or understand very well about scopes, these:

regular, regular_only, incognito_persistent, incognito_session_only

The documentation does not give much detail or give examples, I am making connections but I do not know if I am doing it well because I feel that I am totally ignorant of what I do (connections to proxies).

I want to know the differences and their correct implementation to know when and how to meet the requirements I need when setting up a proxy.
I have always used configurations in regular scope, singleProxy and fixed_servers with an http scheme.

```
config = {
 mode:"fixed_servers",
 rules: {
  singleProxy: {
    scheme: "http",
      host: proxy_host,
      port: parseInt(proxy_port)
  }
 }
};

chrome.proxy.settings.set({
  value: config,
  scope: 'regular'
});
```